# Does Azure Devops Server 2019 include the "Environments" feature

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

We recently upgraded to Azure Devops Server 2019 but i don't see Environments under the Pipeline menu.

Is the Environment feature present in Azure Devops Server 2019?

Comment: It looks like it isn't available. The documentation for Environments only exists for Azure DevOps Services and not for Azure Devops Server (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2019)

Comment: Did you look at the release notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the Environment feature is currently not supported in Azure Devops Server 2019. To use the Environment feature, you need to upgrade to Server 2020. For details,please refer to this [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-in-yaml).

[image]

In addition, you could add your request for supporting this feature on server 2019 on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.